# .net String Format

Tags: c#, .net

Need some help here, I don't kwon how to convert or format that final string.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan final = DateTime.Now.Subtract(
        Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " 00:00"));

        this.lblGeracao.Text =
            (Convert.ToDecimal(40.1714444 * final.TotalSeconds)).ToString() + "*";

        this.lblCO2.Text =
            (Convert.ToInt32(13.1254644 * final.TotalSeconds) / 1000)
            .ToString() + "**";
}
```

I need to convert this number: `40.1714444 * final.TotalSeconds` to somthing like this format `1.175.1453.192`

Now a got this result `1175208394,50231`

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are the additional full stops (.) for?  What values are they separating?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the anti-pattern of creating a string just to parse it.  Try `TimeSpan final = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Format("{0:#,##0}",(Convert.ToDecimal(40.1714444 * final.TotalSeconds)))+ "*";

Comment: Thank you, perfect, a check the documentation like Brian comment and i see some reference to that and I'm could solve with this: ToString("C2") too, thank you.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for the answer vote and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

```
123456.ToString("N0")
```

Will give you `123,456` or `123.456`, dependant on culture.

Answer (score 0):

String.Format is the best option to format a string check the link below it have the explanation of how you can format the string as you wish

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format